# How to construct date range query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My mongo document is as below

```
{{

"startTime" : "2012-12-06T18:30:00.000Z",
"endTime" : "2012-12-07T18:30:00.000Z",
"cost" : "40",
"_id" : ObjectId("50c31b65d2dfa2271b000001")
}
{

"startTime" : "2012-12-07T18:30:00.000Z",
"endTime" : "2012-12-08T18:30:00.000Z",
"cost" : "40",
"_id" : ObjectId("50c31b65d2dfa2271b000001")
}
{

"startTime" : "2012-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
"endTime" : "2012-12-07T18:30:00.000Z",
"cost" : "40",
"_id" : ObjectId("50c31b65d2dfa2271b000001")
}
}
```

I have tried to query the mongo document based on the date range, 
my query is as follows:

```
db.collection.find({"startTime":{"$gte":"2012-12-05T18:30:00.000Z"},"endTime":  {"$lt":"2012-12-12T18:30:00.000Z"}});
```

Response is null...

Comment: Something's off here as the three documents in your example all have the same `_id`.

Comment: I tried this exact query with collection with your first document in it and I got back this document.  Are you sure these are your exact documents and your exact query?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query as follows and it will return the result as expected.

```
db.collection.find({"startTime":{"$gte":ISODate("2012-12-05T18:30:00.000Z")},"endTime":  {"$lt":ISODate("2012-12-12T18:30:00.000Z")}});
```

Comment: i am creating query in javascript ISODate is not defined, whether i want to add any library?

Comment: If you just store date as a string then your query should work, or if you store it as ISODate then query i wrote could help. You don't need to add any library for ISODate.